# How to put watcher json to watcher using aws glue job

Tags: python, aws-glue

I have a watcher json data I want to put it to the watcher in kibana from the aws glue job how to achieve this

I need a watcher to be created with the data that is given in the python glue job. Hoe to put the json to watcher in kibana in dev tools we can simply use PUT command to create a watcher but through api how to get this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.